# How to store map containing list of objects using Spring Boot and PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

I'm very new to Spring Boot.

I have an entity that basically is a kind of "tier list". It is used as a ranking of objects. Multiple objects could be in the same rank.

So I represent it as HashMap<Integer, LinkedList<ObjectsToRank>>. The map key is the rank, associated with list of ObjectsToRank.

Tier list entity:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "classements")
public class ClassementEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_classement")
    private  Long id_classement;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_agent")
    private AgentEntity agent;

    @Column(name = "max_rank")
    private Integer max_rank;
    
    private HashMap<Integer, LinkedList<PeriodeProtocolaireEntity>> mapRang;

}
```

So my question is how can I store it in my PostgreSQL DB ?

I thought about Jsonb column that would look like:

```json
{
    mapKeyInteger: [
            PeriodeProtocolaireEntity.id,
            PeriodeProtocolaireEntity.id,
    ],
    2: ...
}
```

But I don't know how to do it in a good way with Spring Boot or if there is a better way.

Comment: How is there still no answer, Im looking to find a solution to this as well but it seems nobody knows. Did you end up solving it?

Comment: @DavidFariña I finally did it with the Jsonb collumn and it works fine. But I still don't know if it's the best way to do it or if it isn't optimised.

Comment: i thought about that as well but ended up making a new table entity. Seemed somewhat cleaner for my case but made the creating/updating the data a bit more complicated.